# PHP POST METHOD Undefined Index

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I am trying to implement the creating topic part in forum

Why I can't use the another php file, say b.php to get data that sent from a.php?

```
$topic=$_POST['title'];
$detail=$_POST['content'];
$name=$_POST['username'];
```

Errors show message that undefined index at these 3 inputs.

Comment: Post source from b.php and a.php. Your question is far too vague. Show us how the form is submitted.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use? If the code above is your `b.php` I don't see any reason why you can't make such `post` on it. `<form action='b.php' method='post'>`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling this script without sending `POST` data.

Use it in following way:

```
$topic  = empty($_POST['title'])  ? null : $_POST['title'];
$detail = empty($_POST['detail']) ? null : $_POST['detail'];
$name   = empty($_POST['name'])   ? null : $_POST['name'];
```

It will avoid errors and if you just request script without `POST`ing, variables will contain null values

Comment: But the problem is when I submit these information, there is no even  u-date to databse and my b.php cannot help me add the topic since they check the input field is null.

Comment: used, but not sure why the array is empty even I have submit the information at a.php